# What are the authentication options available with Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My current project is in rails 2.3.5 which uses restful authentication. I am moving this app to rails 3.. I want to know about the compatibility of authentication plugins with rails 3.

Can i use authlogic with rails 3 ? Is it reliable ?

what other options do I have for a very simple user authentication to work with rails 3 ?

thanks

Comment: devise is getting a lot of steam because of nice rails 3 compatibility and more because it is rack based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend devise (http://github.com/plataformatec/devise). I found it very easy to get up and running on rails3.

- It has tons of features.
- It is actively being developed.
- It has specific instructions for use with Rails3.
- I could go on, but I think you get the idea :)

Comment: +1 for devise. It works great and is really well integrated in Rails3.